# Strange behaviour with php active class

Tags: php, css, if-statement

I have some code where i need to insert a class called **active** within the  link tag. But for some really weird reason it wont work even though the values match and it really should only make the beef menu item blue and not the others. Screenshot attached.

```
if($menuitems->title==$menutitle) { 

$activemenu='active'; 

}

echo '<a href="#menu_'.$cid.'" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success '.$activemenu.'" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu" >'.$menuitems->title.' / '.$menutitle.' / '.$menuitems->title.'</a>';
```

**$menu->title** does only equal beef but yet its inseting teh active classs intoall the other top level menus.

[image]

Thanks for your help :)
Jonny

Comment: Reset `$activemenu` variable. `$activemenu = ''`

Comment: @Samir - where do i put that? before the if sttament? i also have all of this inside a foreach

Comment: Yes add before the if statement. If it doesn't work can post your php code.

Comment: @Samir please put yours as answer. It worked. All i had to do was place it inside the foreach and not ouside the foreasch. It works now. Thank you Samir. I willl give you the tick if you answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting `$activemenu` variable will fix it before `if` statement or inside `foreach`.

```
$activemenu = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$activemenu = '';
if($menuitems->title==$menutitle) 
{ 
    $activemenu='active'; 
}
?>
<a href="#menu_<?php echo $cid ;?>" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success <?php echo $activemenu; ?>" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu" ><?php echo $menuitems->title . ' / ' . $menutitle .' / '. $menuitems->title; ?></a>
```

I'd suggest you to go with this. Honestly, I myself got stuck in these type of situations before. It's always better to have `<a>` tags outside php.

Comment: Thank you @Akshay and in most times i do use that method. BUt tgis code was already written like this format so i have kept the same formatting to avoid confusion. Samir has helped solve it - thank you to both :)

Comment: OK great :) Just thought it would help you.